# Cannot send SES email from Cognito (CDK) (NOT IN SANDBOX)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, amazon-ses

I cannot use a verified email in SES with the email property of a `CognitoUserPool`.

I have a verified email identity set up in SES. The SES account is out of sandbox mode. The SES account is in `us-east-1`.

When I go to create a cognito userpool in my CDK stack

```js
const clientUserPool = new cognito.UserPool(
      this,
      'userpool',
      {
        ...
        selfSignUpEnabled: true,
        email: cognito.UserPoolEmail.withSES({
          fromEmail: '<my-verified-email>'
          sesRegion: 'us-east-1',
        }),
      }
```

I get the following error when I deploy:
`Cognito received the following error from Amazon SES when attempting to send email: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:<accountId>:identity/<my-verified-email>(Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: <requestId>; Proxy: null)`

When I try to do the equivalent in the AWS Console, it works fine.

1. Navigate to user pool
2. Go to "Messaging"
3. Configure user pool to use SES with the email .

CDK CLI Version: 1.144.0
Framework Version: 1.144.0
Node.js Version: 14
OS: MacOS

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/creating-identities.html#verify-email-addresses-procedure ? Can you send a test email if you follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-an-email-from-console.html#send-test-email ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I thought the email address was verified but it wasn't, unfortunately the new SES UI displays "Verified" when it actually isn't.

When you verify an email address, AWS will send an email to that address with a link to verify the address, if you are trying to use an email address like no-reply@yourdomain.com you need to setup an "Email Receiving" rule for that address so AWS can receive emails for the address and forward that to SNS and then SNS forward that to an email address you can access.

You can find detailed instructions [here](https://matthewbonig.com/2018/05/02/aws-verifying-outgoing-ses-email-addresses-without-an-email-server/)

In order to allow AWS to receive emails on your behalf, you also need to setup MX and TXT records for your domain.

You can check the verification status of your email address using the CLI:

```
aws ses get-identity-verification-attributes --identities "user1@example.com" "user2@example.com"
```

[get-identity-verification-attributes](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ses/get-identity-verification-attributes.html)

[Email receiving with Amazon SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/receiving-email.html)

Comment: Saved me hours from going crazy. It's quite a critical bug in AWS! Thanks.